# Passing two arguments to a function when using filter

Tags: python, function, filter, arguments

I have a list of words . I wants to filter out words which do not have minimum length. I tried filter, but showing some error . My code is

```
def words_to_integer(x,y):
          return len(x)> y


print("enter the list of words : ")
listofwords =  [ str(x)  for x in input().split()]  #list of words 
minimumlength = print("enter the length ")          
z = list(filter(words_to_integer,(listofwords,minimumlength)))

print("words with length greater than ",minimumlength ,"are" ,z )
```

error is

```
 z = list(filter(words_to_integer,(listofwords,minimumlength)))
 TypeError: words_to_integer() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

z = filter(partial(words_to_integer, y=minimumlength), listofwords)
```

`partial(words_to_integer, y=minimumlength)` is the same function as `words_to_integer`, but with argument `y` being fixed at `minimumlength`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You need to pass a function that already knows about minimumlength.

One easy way to do this would be to use a lambda instead of your standalone function:

```
filter(lambda x: len(x) > minimumlength, listofwords)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you type this

```
list(filter(words_to_integer,(listofwords,minimumlength)))
```

python tries to do something like this:

```
z = []
if words_to_integer(listofwords):
    z.append(listofwords)
if words_to_integer(minimumlength):
    z.append(minimumlength)
```

which will fail, because `words_to_integer` accepts 2 arguments, but only one was given.

You probably want something like this:

```
z = []
for word in listofwords:
    if words_to_integer(word):
        z.append(word)
```

which looks like this with `filter`:

```
z = list(filter(lambda word: words_to_integer(word, minimumlength), listofwords))
```

or use `partial` like in the other answer.